# After setting DoubleBuffered true panels turn black and show old screen contents

Tags: windows, delphi, c++builder

When `DoubleBuffered` is false, panels have `clBtnFace` coloring at runtime. When I set `DoubleBuffered` to true, blank areas on the panel show black, or show the contents from a previous screen. It's as if the background isn't being erased.

If I set `DoubleBuffered` to false and use this:

```cpp
void __fastcall TMain::CreateParams(TCreateParams &Params)
{
    Params.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
    TForm::CreateParams(Params);
}
```

Then the panels behave normally.

Is turning on `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` on the base form not the same thing as setting `DoubleBuffered` to true on the base form when all child controls have their `ParentDoubleBuffered` set to true?

Update: Setting the offending panels' ParentBackground=false; (never knew that property existed) solved some but not all of the overwriting / black fill ins. The rest remains a mystery.

Comment: No, they are not the same. The VCL does not use `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` at all, double-buffering is implemented manually using an in-memory bitmap, or DWM compositing if Aero Glass is enabled. And FYI, you should be calling the base class `CreateParams()` *before* modifying `Params`, otherwise you risk the base class overriding your custom settings.

Comment: Remy, if I call TForm::CreateParams(Params) before the |= line I get a form where the buttons and tabs keep appearing and disappearing, the scroll bars jump up and down and I have to reset the programme in the IDE to regain control.

Comment: Simple solution. Don't set DoubleBuffered True.

Comment: I'd like to understand what's happening though David especially as using WS_EX_COMPOSITED turns the app into an animation unless I set the Params.ExStyle in the 'wrong' order.

Comment: Just don't use `DoubleBuffered`, it doesn't end well, and don't use `WS_EX_COMPOSITED`.

Comment: David, I've been through the mill as far as trying to stop flickering is concerned and some day I'd like to think I'll know enough to implement my own buffering. In the meantime though I'd settle for being able to fathom the following - If I create a new C++ VCL Forms Application, place a TTabSet on the form and place a TPanel inside the TTabSet the panel shows as white despite its Color=clBtnFace. If I then set the Form's DoubleBuffered=true the panel Color changes to clBtnface. Are TPanels transparent by default and why does setting the base form's DoubleBuffered=true change that?

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using ? I remember delphi 7 and earlier having problems with panels on windows 7 and higher

Comment: Guido, I'm using C++ builder 10.1.

Comment: This is the wrong way to deal with flickering period.

Comment: Could you enlarge on that David? I'm currently googling "implement your own double buffering" as that's the road I'd like to go down so that control is in my own hands.